# Simple inequality, proof

Tags: proof-verification

There is a following inequality

$$\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2}}{n}\geq\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2}+2x_{1}x_{2}+...+2x_{1}x_{n}+2x_{2}x_{3}+...+2x_{2}x_{n}+...+2x_{n-1}x_{n}}{n^{2}}.$$

In my opinion, it is held for all $x_i>0$. It can be rewritten to the following form 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2}}{n} & \geq & \frac{2x_{1}x_{2}+...+2x_{1}x_{n}+2x_{2}x_{3}+...+2x_{2}x_{n}+...+2x_{n-1}x_{n}}{n^{2}},\\
x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2} & \geq & \frac{2x_{1}x_{2}+...+2x_{1}x_{n}+2x_{2}x_{3}+...+2x_{2}x_{n}+...+2x_{n-1}x_{n}}{\left(n-1\right)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

However, how to proof the last inequlity? I used 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2} & \geq & \frac{2}{n-1}\frac{n!}{\left(n-2\right)!2!}E(x_{i}x_{j}),\\
x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2} & \geq & nE(x_{i}x_{j})
\end{eqnarray*}

which may not be correct. However, there must be a more rigorous and simple proof.

Comment: How do you know that the inequality holds even when you multiply the RHS by $\frac{n-1}{n}<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality can be rewritten as:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\geq \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^2}{n}
\end{align*}

Let us fix $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i  = c$. Then, the problem:
\begin{align*}
   \mbox{minimize} &\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \\
    \mbox{subject to} &\; \\
     &\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = c,\\
     & x_i \geq 0, 
\end{align*} 
has the solution $c^2/n$, when $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=c/n$. Now, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \geq \frac{c^2}{n} = \frac{(\sum_ i x_i)^2}{n}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Expand

$$ \sum_{i<j} (x_i - x_j)^2.$$